# Laravel migration issue

Tags: laravel-4

I have an issue with the composer for creating migrations.

I just installed Laravel 4.2 via composer.

But i want to make migrations for my DB via composer, so i typed this command below:

> php artisan migrate:make create_user_table

But then i get the error:

(I've tried it again to install Laravel 4.2, but i still get this error.)

> Could not open input file: artisan

How can i fix this?

Comment: Are you running this command from within project's folder? Do you see the "artisan" file there?

Comment: So my Laravel 4.2 project is in my xampp/htdocs, and there i don't have the artisan file. But there's an artisan file in /system

Comment: What are the actions you did so far? It seems that you haven't initialized/created the project yet

Comment: Problem solved. My "artisan" file is in my /system folder so i did cd system and then i ran the command: php artisan migrate:make create_user_table and it worked!

Comment: It helps if you write up your solutions as answers. Otherwise people like me go through old questions looking for ones without answers, just to find that you've answered it in a question. Thanks!